# How to delay invocation of @Schedule bean?

Tags: java-ee-6, seam, ejb-3.1, seam3

I have recently migrated an app from SEAM 2.2 > 2.3

In SEAM 2.2.x I used MDB with Quartz for scheduling, now I am using EJB 3.1 I use @Schedule instead

Problem is that on startup the @Schedule beans are being invoked before SEAM has finished starting up, causing the exceptions (see below)

How can I delay the invocation of @Schedule beans? Is there a way to hook this into the SEAM lifecycle?

```
@Singleton
@Name("scheduledActions")
public class ScheduledActionsBean{

    @Logger private Log log;
    @In private Map<String, String> messages;
    @In private StorageActions storageActions;
    @In private UploadDAO uploadDAO;
    @In private ProcessSession processSession;
    @In private WebAppActions webAppActions;
    @In private GlobalSettings globalSettings;

    @In @Out(scope=ScopeType.APPLICATION) private ContainerInstance thisContainer;

    @Schedule(second="1", minute="*", hour="*", persistent=false)
    public void minuteActions(){
        //do stuff here
    }
}


17:02:01,105 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 1) JBAS014120: Error invoking timeout for timer: [id=cd28086f-62fc-4ed8-a43b-c00787dfbca7 timedObjectId=Processor.Processor-ejb.ScheduledActionsBean auto-timer?:true persistent?:false timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@24a5031d initialExpiration=Mon Dec 08 00:00:01 GMT 2014 intervalDuration(in milli sec)=0 nextExpiration=Mon Dec 08 17:03:01 GMT 2014 timerState=IN_TIMEOUT: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:166) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.TimerCMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(TimerCMTTxInterceptor.java:52) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:230) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimedObjectInvokerImpl.callTimeout(TimedObjectInvokerImpl.java:101) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.task.CalendarTimerTask.callTimeout(CalendarTimerTask.java:60) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.task.TimerTask.run(TimerTask.java:132) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.0.0.GA.jar:2.0.0.GA]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:163) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:85) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateless.StatelessSessionComponent$1.create(StatelessSessionComponent.java:66) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateless.StatelessSessionComponent$1.create(StatelessSessionComponent.java:63) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.pool.AbstractPool.create(AbstractPool.java:60) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.pool.strictmax.StrictMaxPool.get(StrictMaxPool.java:123) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to invoke a Seam component outside an initialized application
    at org.jboss.seam.contexts.Lifecycle.getApplication(Lifecycle.java:36)
    at org.jboss.seam.contexts.Lifecycle.setupApplication(Lifecycle.java:134)
    at org.jboss.seam.Seam.componentForName(Seam.java:325)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SessionBeanInterceptor.postConstruct(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptorFactory.java:118) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:95) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:95) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 30 more

17:02:01,149 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 1) JBAS014122: Error during retrying timeout for timer: [id=cd28086f-62fc-4ed8-a43b-c00787dfbca7 timedObjectId=Processor.Processor-ejb.ScheduledActionsBean auto-timer?:true persistent?:false timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@24a5031d initialExpiration=Mon Dec 08 00:00:01 GMT 2014 intervalDuration(in milli sec)=0 nextExpiration=Mon Dec 08 17:03:01 GMT 2014 timerState=RETRY_TIMEOUT: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:166) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.TimerCMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(TimerCMTTxInterceptor.java:52) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:230) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimedObjectInvokerImpl.callTimeout(TimedObjectInvokerImpl.java:101) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.task.CalendarTimerTask.callTimeout(CalendarTimerTask.java:60) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.task.TimerTask.run(TimerTask.java:132) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.0.0.GA.jar:2.0.0.GA]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:163) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:85) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateless.StatelessSessionComponent$1.create(StatelessSessionComponent.java:66) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateless.StatelessSessionComponent$1.create(StatelessSessionComponent.java:63) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.pool.AbstractPool.create(AbstractPool.java:60) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.pool.strictmax.StrictMaxPool.get(StrictMaxPool.java:123) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to invoke a Seam component outside an initialized application
    at org.jboss.seam.contexts.Lifecycle.getApplication(Lifecycle.java:36)
    at org.jboss.seam.contexts.Lifecycle.setupApplication(Lifecycle.java:134)
    at org.jboss.seam.Seam.componentForName(Seam.java:325)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SessionBeanInterceptor.postConstruct(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptorFactory.java:118) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:95) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:95) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 30 more
```

Answer (score 0):

May the @Depends Annotation is good for that.
[Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipvi.html)

Comment: Yes I did try but as @Depends is an EJB annotation I dont think I can reference SEAM components, might be wrong though